# How to specify example on Swagger UI in .NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

I want to specify an example of string input format on swagger for users information purpose.

[image]

what i wanted to do is to put an example below the property ColumnAndSortOrder like "for e.g. Resource, Asc"

Is it possible to do so in .NET Core ?

BTW I'm using swagger UI 3.0

Any help or pointers are welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

you can use these two attributes :

```
    [System.ComponentModel.Description("some description")]
```

or

```
    [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations("some description")]
```

on your apis or properties